# Evaluate rule from stylus variable

Tags: stylus

I'd like to have a `hide` and `show` shorthand to write things like this:

```
hide = 'display: none !important'
show = 'display: block !important'

.my-button
    {show}
    +mobile()
        {hide}
```

There's something like this available in the current Stylus syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@block` for this. See [an example](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=hide%20%3D%20%40block%20%7B%20display%3A%20none%20!important%20%7D%0Ashow%20%3D%20%40block%20%7B%20display%3A%20block%20!important%20%7D%0A%0Amobile()%0A%20%20%40media%20screen%20and%20(max-width%3A%20320px)%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bblock%7D%0A%0A.my-button%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bshow%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2Bmobile()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bhide%7D).